# How to run a .ipynb file once every week automatically on google colaboratory?

Tags: automation, jupyter-notebook, triggers, google-colaboratory, scheduling

I am currently using google colab to access a google drive folder where someone uploads downloaded SPSS files on a particular day of the week. I am using a py-drive to access that file and export it to CSV. At the moment I have to go in manually to my google colab .ipynb notebook and click the run all button from the runtime menu. I want to automate this process by maybe scheduling it? Something similar to setting up triggers in the Google App scripts or scheduling cron jobs. Any workaround would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61762045/running-google-colab-every-day-at-a-specific-time).

If you want the schedule it locally, you have to covert the notebook to a python file. Then follow the steps mention in this [artile](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/schedule-a-python-script-to-run-daily/#:%7E:text=%27%20in%20the%20Actions%20Tab.,%27Daily%27%20and%20click%20Next.). This option is free.

If you want to run the scheduler on a headless cloud server, you might go for GCM, AWS etc. You need to buy credits to use them.