# Schedule running colab notebook to Copy new files added to google drive into google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

I need to copy all new files added to a google drive into a google cloud storage bucket regularly (once per 6 hours)

I followed the steps in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48122091/copy-file-from-google-drive-to-google-cloud-storage-within-google) and when I run colab code it does the job for me.

How can I schedule the colab notebook to run every 6 hours?

Below is the content of my colab:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

project_id = 'dev-project'
!gcloud config set project {project_id}

!gsutil -m cp -n -r /content/drive/My\ Drive/test/* gs://{bucket_name}/
```

Comment: No one able to help?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using Google [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/overview) to run the colab code every 6 hours. Set the target to your Colab notebook URL. In the "Target" section, select "HTTP" as the target type and enter the URL of your Colab notebook. Make sure the URL includes the notebook's runtime ID.

You can consider using this suggestion from [Prakhar Agarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61762045/running-google-colab-every-day-at-a-specific-time), whereas you need to create a notebooks.csv listing all the Colaboratory URLs. Then use `colabctl` to run each notebook (In order, synchronously mentioned in the CSV) and then pauses for a period of n seconds of time before running them again.

then run `python colabctl.py <end-string\> <sleep-seconds\>`,

There's a `gCookies.pkl` file in the repo. Ensure that your local Python version is the same one as used to create this serialized pkl file. You can check this [documentation](https://github.com/bitnom/colabctl) as reference.

Now that we have a notebook and script ready, next is to be able to SSH into Google colab.

- Create an account on [ngrok.com](http://ngrok.com)
- Copy and paste below code in colab which installs ngrok and creates a tunnel
- Now, on your local machine, open terminal and SSH to connect to the Colab System

`ssh` `root@0.tcp.ngrok.io` `-p <port\_num\_generated\_above\>`

Now you have access to the whole system through SSH terminal. And can continue to use colabctl to any other corn script on local environment to execute your remote colab script. You can check this [documentation](https://gist.github.com/yashkumaratri/204755a85977586cebbb58dc971496da#file-google-colab-ssh) for reference.